# How to add in a TListview a TTextButtonObjectAppearance to be visible only on EditMode?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

The ItemEdit has `DynamicAppearance`. I added to it a `TTextButtonObjectAppearance` item. The button is visible in `DesignMode`, but when I get out of `DesignMode` (no matter if I'm on *runtime* or not) the button disappears (with `EditMode` on `true`).

If I add it to Item (in normal mode) it is visible.

How should I add a button to be visible only on `EditMode`?

Comment: Exactly my problem. Did you solve this?

Comment: @DavidU No. I ended up rethinking the application.